# 555 Timer works perfectly until solenoid connected to relay then continuously triggers

Tags: timer, 555, solenoid

Note: the solenoid text in the image is just a representation.

Real world everything is fine until I connect the solenoid to the Com and N/O of the relay. It then cycles once and starts to continuously re-trigger on it's own once a second or so. I disconnect the solenoid and it works as it should.

I have used the common 12V as in the image and I have also given the solenoid it's own separate 12V but it makes no difference.

[image]

Comment: *everything is fine until I connect the solenoid to the Com and N/O of the relay* - that would be an incorrect connection and one that just plainly wouldn't work and do nothing. Unless of course you mean the NC connection as per your (ahem) schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka Actually, that appears to be the NO connection, given that the output of the 555 is currently high.

Comment: Then what has been posted is not a schematic diagram then.

Comment: Hearth you are correct. That is the output of a simulation currently high on the output. Any ideas as to why it fails when the solenoid is in the cct and running. Real world breadboard failure not simulation.

Comment: What has the supply got in it, that's not shown. Any supply decoupling you've missed off?

Comment: It's those portable 12V switch mode power packs.

Comment: There should be a second diode between the branch to the LED and the branch to the snubber diode, (cathode to snubber diode)  to prevent the 555's output being pulled 0.7V below ground when the 555's output goes low to switch  the relay off. As things stand, when the relay switches off, the back emf pulls the 555's output below ground which can retrigger the 555. Not entirely sure this missing diode is causing your problem though!

Comment: No luck, no effect whatsoever with the additional diode. The problem is when the solenoid is in the circuit which is isolated by the relay itself and if I then also give it its own 12V from another power pack completely isolating it it still does it. Somehow when the solenoid is de-energized it affects the circuit even though it's isolated from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, and as always the answer is in the question. The solenoid when in the circuit causes the problem.

I had the 555 trigger wire from a sensor alongside the solenoid wires and no shielding. Solenoid de-energizes sending RF interference to the trigger. Never ending loop.

Thanks for the help.